# pandas agg() with mean(standalone vs list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I'm digging into pandas aggregator function while working with a wine reviews dataset. To aggregate points given by wine reviewers, I noticed that, when I used *mean* as a standalone function in agg():

```
reviewer_mean_ratings = reviews.groupby('taster_name').points.agg('mean')
```

The output looks like this:

[image: reviewer-ratings-output]

Noticed that the output has 2 columns(at least that's what it looks like *visually*). But

```
type(reviewer_mean_ratings) = pandas.core.series.Series
```

**Is that just 1 column with space between the name and mean rating? I'm confused.**

Also noticed that, I cannot sort this output in descending order by the mean ratings. Instead if I had used *mean* as a list in agg() then descending order works using *sort_values()* method later.

**My hypothesis is that if I want to access the mean ratings column later, the only way to do it is to use agg(['mean']) instead of agg('mean') in the original query. Am I mistaken somewhere?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the following statement works to get descending order by using 'mean' as a standalone function in agg() method.

```
reviews.groupby('taster_name').points.agg('mean').sort_values(ascending=False)
```

i.e. don't use the *"by"* clause in sort_values() method.

Answer (score 0):

The output is a pandas Series, sort of like a 1-column Dataframe with index. To get the actual values of the Series, just add '.values':

```
reviewer_mean_ratings = reviews.groupby('taster_name').points.agg('mean').values
```

This will output the values as a numpy array.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that if I just use the following statement I can get the descending order of ratings without using 'mean' as a list. Next answer describes the solution.